# Fast way to write data to multiple files - Objective-C OSX

Tags: objective-c, nsfilehandle, nsoutputstream

Currently, I'm serially creating/writing data to ~30,000 files using this code:

```
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[_output_url path]]) {
        //file already exists, append string to it
        NSFileHandle *aFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:[_output_url path]];
        [aFileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [aFileHandle writeData:[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    } else {
        //create file
        [dataString writeToFile:[_output_url path] atomically:YES encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
    }
```

As you can guess, it takes quite a bit of time for this to run through 30k files. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to make this more efficient. I've looked at NSOutputStream - would this be a viable alternative? Or am I always limited by the speed at which the system can write the data to a file?

Comment: how often will you come back to a file after writing to it?  almost never or almost always, or only after the application or routine is run again?

Comment: Almost always. I first write a little bit of data to all 30k files (initial file creation) -- then I write small bits of data to each file many times. Sometimes 5000 times.